# Get GIT Submodule history only until a specified date in history

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a main project and a bunch of submodule libraries inside it. The below gave me a truncated history. (I dont care what happened before this)

```
git clone --shallow-since=2021-01-01 <SOME_REPO>
```

Now, I would like to clone a submodule in the same super project, but I do not see the option of --shallow-since. All I see is --depth.

```
git submodule update --init --depth=<VALUE> --recommend-shallow <SUBMODULE_2>
```

- How do I only get the history from 2021-01-01 for SUBMODULE_2?
- Is there a equivalent conversion from --shallow-since to --depth?

I am using git version 2.33.1